# How to use Hadoop's MapFileOutputFormat in Flink?

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink, sequencefile

I've got stuck while I'm writing a program using Apache Flink. The problem is that I'm trying to generate [Hadoop's MapFile](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/MapFile.html) as a result of computation but Scala compiler complains about type mismatch.

To illustrate the problem, let me show you the below code snippet which tries to generate two kinds of output: one is [Hadoop's SequenceFile](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.html) and the other is MapFile.

```
val dataSet: DataSet[(IntWritable, BytesWritable)] =
  env.readSequenceFile(classOf[Text], classOf[BytesWritable], inputSequenceFile.toString)
    .map(mapper(_))
    .partitionCustom(partitioner, 0)
    .sortPartition(0, Order.ASCENDING)

val seqOF = new HadoopOutputFormat(
  new SequenceFileOutputFormat[IntWritable, BytesWritable](), Job.getInstance(hadoopConf)
)

val mapfileOF = new HadoopOutputFormat(
  new MapFileOutputFormat(), Job.getInstance(hadoopConf)
)

val dataSink1 = dataSet.output(seqOF)  // it typechecks!
val dataSink2 = dataSet.output(mapfileOF) // syntax error
```

As commented above, dataSet.output(mapfileOF) causes Scala compiler to complain as follows:
[image]
FYI, compared to SequenceFile, MapFile calls for a stronger condition that a key must be WritableComparable.

Before writing the application using Flink, I implemented it using Spark as below and it worked okay (no compilation error and it runs okay without any error).

```
val rdd = sc
  .sequenceFile(inputSequenceFile.toString, classOf[Text], classOf[BytesWritable])
  .map(mapper(_))
  .repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(partitioner)

rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
  outputPath.toString,
  classOf[IntWritable],
  classOf[BytesWritable],
  classOf[MapFileOutputFormat]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/batch/hadoop_compatibility.html#using-hadoop-outputformats

It contains the following example:

```scala
// Obtain your result to emit.
val hadoopResult: DataSet[(Text, IntWritable)] = [...]

val hadoopOF = new HadoopOutputFormat[Text,IntWritable](
  new TextOutputFormat[Text, IntWritable],
  new JobConf)

hadoopOF.getJobConf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", " ")
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(hadoopOF.getJobConf, new Path(resultPath))

hadoopResult.output(hadoopOF)
```

Comment: I've never had problems with other Hadoop file output formats like TextOutputFormat in your code snippet and SequenceFileOutputFormat in my code snippet. MapFileOutFormat is not like these file output formats.

Comment: No sure... Maybe you can ask at user@flink.apache.org (you need to subscribe first: https://flink.apache.org/community.html#mailing-lists)